# Python built-in methods

Tags: python

Assume:

```
>> a = 128
>> dir(a)
['__abs__', ..., '__xor__', 'bit_length', 'conjugate', 'denominator', 'imag', 'numerator', 'real']
```

The instruction:

```
>> dir(128)
['__abs__', ..., '__xor__', 'bit_length', 'conjugate', 'denominator', 'imag', 'numerator', 'real']
```

returns the same exactly previous result.

I can't explain why

```
>> a.bit_length()
8
```

works correctly but

```
>> 128.bit_length()
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    128.bit_length()
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

throws a SyntaxError.

The second 128 is "parsed" a new `int` object should be created in memory. Why it can't access the method?

Comment: The parser sees the `.` and thinks it's a floating point number.

Comment: Long answer cut short, Put it in parenthesis, `(128).bit_length()`

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting: it thinks the `.bit` is part of the number.